# Longest string in alphabetic order

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code works fine for all the strings, except for the ones where the last char is needed.

```
s='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
sub =''
test =s[0]

for n in range(len(s)-1):
    if len(test) > len(sub):
        sub = test
    if s[n] >= s[n-1]:
        test += s[n]
    else:
        test = s[n]

print 'Longest substring in alphabetic order is: ' + str(sub)
```

How do you suggest a possibility for doing this?

Thank you in advance guys!

PS:

Thanks for the answers so far. The problem is that, no matter which range I type, the sub variable, which I will print, doesn't get all the chars I want. The loop finishes before :\ Maybe it's a problem with the program itself.

Any extra tips? :)

Comment: Also, you have a typo in `print 'Logest substring...` it should say `Longest` (as in your title). /nitpicking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with `range(len(s)-1)`. Range generates a list up to its upper limit parameter value-1 so you don't need to subtract1 to len(s), use:

```
range(len(s))
```

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

> range(stop)
>   range(start, stop[, step])
>   This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero

On the other hand, you are labeling your question as python2.7 so I assume you are using 2.7. If that is the case, it is more efficient to use `xrange` instead `range` because that way you will use an iterator instead generating a list.

**EDIT**

From the comments to this question, you can change your code to:

```
s='caabcdab'
sub =''
test =s[0]

for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
    n = i%len(s)
    if len(test) > len(sub):
        sub = test
        if i >= len(s):
            break
    if s[n] >= s[n-1]:
        test += s[n]
    else:
        test = s[n]

print 'Logest substring in alphabetic order is: ' + str(sub)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pablo. The problem is that, no matter which range I type, the sub variable, which I will print, doesn't get all the chars I want. The loop finishes before :\ Maybe it's a problem with the program itself.

Comment: @makemesteaks: That's because you assign test to sub before it completes the check in the loop. Thus the last check succeeds but the updated string is not assigned to sub. :)

Comment: @makemesteaks Your algorithm requires to iterate to one more character in order to be able to assign the last result. Try with: `for i in range(len(s)+1): n = i%len(s)`

Comment: Thanks Rajan! check my answer just below. I just assigned the check to the end of the loop

I will now check with different cases and I'll keep you updated

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys. If I move the `if len(test) > len(sub): sub = test` to the end of the loop, it doesn't work also. Plus, the your edit code, doesnt' work also for some other test cases as for example: **s = 'ocunhyfwiyizqh'** should be **cu** and I get **oo**, for example. Sorry guys, but this is becoming such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Finally! Thanks! :) Now I will study this code! Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

you `enemurate` instead of range:

```
 s='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

sub =''
test =s[0]

for n,value in enumerate(s):
    if len(test) > len(sub):
        sub = test
    if value >= s[n-1]:
        test += s[n]
    else:
        test = s[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do use the following code:

```
s = 'abcdefgahijkblmnopqrstcuvwxyz'
sub = ''
test = s[0]

for index, character in enumerate(s):
    if index > 0:
        if character > s[index - 1]:
            test += character
        else:
            test = character
    if len(test) > len(sub):
        sub = test
print 'Longest substring in alphabetic order is: ' + str(sub)
```

A few pointers too.

1. Python strings are iterable. i.e you can loop through them.
2. Use enumerate when you want the index of the list while iterating it.